# Read line "arguments" easily

Tags: python

I've got a question:

Given the input, for example: `numberOfBrothers=5 anyFemale=yes`
i want to autofill an object fields, for example:

```
def Person (self, input):
      self.brothers = input.numberOfBrothers
```

The first thing I did was

```
john = Person(line.split(' '))
```

So I've got

```
numberOfBrothers=5 anyFemale=yes
```

Can I do this in a simpler way, without splitting again in the "=" ?

Comment: Use a dedicated argument parser, ie argparse

Comment: The easiest way is probably to use Split(). https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-split/

Comment: No, you need to split on `=` as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to split on whitespace, then split again on `=`, to get at least a list of key/value pairs, which we can turn into a `dict`.

```
>>> line = "numberOfBrothers=5 anyFemale=yes"
>>> [kv.split("=") for kv in line.split()]
[['numberOfBrothers', '5'], ['anyFemale', 'yes']]
>>> dict(_)
{'numberOfBrothers': '5', 'anyFemale': 'yes'}
```

The `dict` can then be used to supply keyword arguments to the call to `Person`, which we'll adjust to

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.brothers = kwargs['numberOfBrothers']
```

Now we can instantiate the class with

```
john = Person(**dict([kv.split("=") for kv in line.split()]))
```

The `**` syntax unpacks the dict, and each key/value pair is used as a separate keyword argument.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably be using `re.finditer` for that:

```
import re

class Person(object):

    def __init__(self, input):
        for match in re.finditer(r"(\w+)=(\w+)", input):
            attr_name, attr_value = match.groups()
            setattr(self, attr_name, attr_value)

john = Person("numberOfBrothers=5 anyFemale=yes")
print(john.numberOfBrothers, john.anyFemale)
```